# How do I design a class to be extendable in two separate ways?

Tags: c#, oop

I am getting started with OOP and I have a question about how to properly design my classes in this scenario:

Imagine that I want to create an algebra library. I would represent any expression as a tree, with each node either being a leaf variable or constant, or a parent operation such as + or ^.

I also want this expression to be able to be evaluated in many different ways. I want to allow different methods to be used for evaluating the expression as a float, or an int, or a rational, etc. as each method of evaluation has different benefits and drawbacks.

This means that I have two separate ways that a potential user of my library may want to expand my expression class - either adding a new node type (i.e. a new operation) or adding a new evaluation method.

To allow for the addition of new node types I would use inheritance - I can use an abstract base class to represent an expression, and then a user of the library can simply override this class to create a new operation:

```cs
abstract class Expression
{
    public abstract float Evaluate();
}

class Addition : Expression
{
    Expression a;
    Expression b;

    public override float Evaluate()
    {
        return a.Evaluate() + b.Evaluate();
    }
}

etc...
```

But then to allow for the addition of new evaluation methods I would use a separate evaluation class to move the evaluation method out of the Expression class:

```cs
abstract class Expression
{
    public abstract float Evaluate();
}

class Addition : Expression
{
    Expression a;
    Expression b;
}

abstract class ExpressionEvaluator<T>
{
    public abstract T Evaluate(Expression e);
}

class FloatExpressionEvaluator : ExpressionEvaluator<float>
{
    public override float Evaluate(Expression e)
    { 
        switch (e)
        {
        case Addition addition:
            return Evaluate(addition.a) + Evaluate(addition.b);
        etc...
        }
    }
}
```

But this method doesn't allow for additional operations to be added. It also feels like it would be very error prone as there is no compile-time checking that all of the classes have a case in the evaluate method.

Is there any way to have an Expression class that is extendable in both directions, with compile time checking that all expressions can be used in all evaluation methods?

Comment: You could look up "double dispatch" and "visitor pattern".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches, but since you want a generic approach, I advise you to use `MiscUtil` it's a generic library which has generic operators (Add, Subtract..etc). You can use it in your code, and it will ease things for you.

For operators, there is no need to create a class for each operator, as their functionalities are one-to-one. For instance, `Addition` class, will only contain addition operator (a + b). There is no complex math to it. So, what I suggest is to use `method` for these operators instead. and focus on the main class. The main class can contain many operators as needed. Some are simple (like addition, subtract ..etc.) others might be complex. For the simple operators, keep it simple, while for the complex operators, you might need to implement some classes for them to simplify them.

For the implementation design itself, I think Fluent API would be more beneficial in your case. So, imagine the library usage would be something like this :

```
// would result 30 (as double).
var result = 
    new ExpressionOperator<double>(15.5)
                .Add(15)
                .Subtract(0.5)
                .Evaluate();
```

This would be implemented like this (using `MiscUtil` lib) :

```
public sealed class ExpressionOperator<T> where T : struct
{
    private T _result;

    public ExpressionOperator(T a)
    {
        _result = a;
    }

    public ExpressionOperator<T> Add(T b)
    {
        _result = Operator.Add(_result, b);
        return this;
    }

    public ExpressionOperator<T> Subtract(T b)
    {
        _result = Operator.Subtract(_result , b);
        return this;
    }

    public T Evaluate() => _result;

    public static explicit operator T(ExpressionOperator<T> exp) => exp._result; 
}
```

Then, it depends on how you'll use it and expand it to fit your needs.

Comment: This solves the specific example I gave, but doesn't solve the overall issue of doing this for any such problem. I'll mark this as the solution anyway, but Klaus' comment about Visitor patterns has solved my question in a more abstract way